# Can we perform automation testing on voice overs?

Tags: automation, voiceover

I want to validate what voice over says on my app
Can i automate voice overs or it can be done only manually?

Answer (score 0):

1/. Use `Unit Tests` to check every property of your accessible elements *(label, hint, trait...)*.

2/. Take a look at the [DEQUE solution](https://www.deque.com/blog/new-worldspace-attest-mobile-ios/) dedicated to iOS.

3/. The `GTXiLib` [open source framework](https://www.google.com/accessibility/blog/post/GTXiLib-announce/) is also a good solution even if it's written in ObjC.  :o)

However, UI Testing *(Xcode 10, iOS 12)* is off the table because custom actions for instance are unreachable.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56544813/3825084) given by an Apple engineer during the WWDC 2019.

Comment: Its not of the table, but very very hard to do in this case. It would be possible by combining XCTest framework and Core ML 2 framework (machine learning), but again - it would probably take months just to create a functioning prototype.